# 悲観的ロックとトランザクション分離レベルの関係性がよくわからない

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle

悲観的ロックの例でよく登場する `SELECT FOR UPDATE` があります。
一方で、トランザクション分離レベルというものがあります。

[トランザクション分離レベル - Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%88%E3%83%A9%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B6%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%E5%88%86%E9%9B%A2%E3%83%AC%E3%83%99%E3%83%AB) からトランザクション分離レベルについての説明の一部を引用すると

> ANSI/ISO SQL標準で定められている分離レベルは、下記の4種類で定義されている。
>
> SERIALIZABLE（直列化可能）
>   REPEATABLE READ（読み取り対象のデータを常に読み取る）
>   READ COMMITTED（確定した最新データを常に読み取る）
>   READ UNCOMMITTED（確定していないデータまで読み取る）

とあります。 `SELECT FOR UPDATE`は上記4つでいうと、どれなんでしょうか？（SERIALIZABLEが該当？）それともまったく違う概念なのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

どのようにトランザクション分離レベルを実装するかが、RDB ごとに少し違っていた記憶があるので、 MySQL に限定して回答を行います。

MySQL においては、トランザクション分離レベルと `SELECT FOR UPDATE` は、共に、トランザクションを並列でさばくための機構です。

MySQL において、トランザクション間の整合性は、次のような原則で動作します。

1. トランザクションが一環した読み込みを行う必要がある場合(e.g. REPEATABLE READ)、整合性を担保するべき時刻(e.g. トランザクション開始時刻)と undo log を利用して、その時刻相当のデータを常に読み込む。
2. トランザクションが書き込みを行う場合、データベースの最新の値を更新する。競合する更新がある場合、それはロックによって排他制御を行い、トランザクション間の整合性が崩れないようにする。

これを実現するために、 MySQL(+innodb)は、 shared lock (読み取りロック)と exclusive lock (書き込みロック)を内部機構として持っています。 shared lock と exclusive lock は同一対象に対して、同時には取得できません。 shared lock は、 shared lock であれば、そのロックを共有できます。 (セマフォのような動作になります) exclusive lock は mutex のような挙動です。

これら lock を用いるとどうしてトランザクション分離レベルが実装できるかというと、一番条件が厳しい serializable がどうなっているか、を例示すれば、雰囲気がなんとなく分かるかな、と思っています。 MySQL において、トランザクションに serializable を指定する、ということは、

1. その読み込み(select) に対しては shared lock の取得が勝手に行われます。
2. 書き込みに対しては exclusive lock が取得されます。

これによって、直列化不能になるような競合するトランザクションたちが実行された場合、 MySQL ではどちらかが wait します。(おたがいがおたがいを wait すると、 deadlock になります。)

以上が、 MySQL においてトランザクション分離がどのように実現されているかを説明しました。内部的には、 shared lock と exclusive lock という機構でこれが実現されています。 `SELECT FOR UPDATE` は、 select しながら exclusive lock を敢えて取得しろ、ということを意味する構文です。なので、トランザクション分離レベルも、 `SELECT FOR UPDATE`も、少くとも MySQL においては、内部の lock の挙動をどのように行うか、という意味での並列実行制御のレベルの話で、同じレイヤーの話である、と個人的には考えています。

Comment: 内部的にはロックを使っているので同じレイヤーの話であることは理解できました。

しかし、おそらく私が理解できてないだけと思うのですが、
「shared lock と exclusive lock は同一対象に対して、同時には取得できません」と「その読み込み(select) に対しては shared lock の取得が勝手に行われます。書き込みに対しては exclusive lock が取得されます。」
が矛盾しているように思えてしまいました（同時に取得できないのに、serializableの場合は同時に取得できる？？）

そこでもう少し調べてみました。
shared lockでは日本語で検索しづらいので`共有ロック`で検索しました。

`共有ロック`で調べてみると`共有ロック`は自他共にWRITEができないとありました。https://qiita.com/daiching/items/835fa37de22b397eece0
共有ロックは自分も書き込めなくなってしまうのであれば、shared lockしているserializableでは書き込み処理ができなくなってしまいます。

ということで、やっぱりよくわからなくなってしまいました...

Comment: shared lock と exclusive lock は同一対象に対して、"他トランザクション"は同時には取得できません（"自トランザクション"は両方取得できます）という意味でしょうか

Comment: 上記の意味ならば矛盾しなくなるので、残す疑問は1つで、 `共有ロック`だと自他ともに書き込みできないというネットの情報があるので、serializableが shared lock を取得するのであれば、書き込み処理ができなくなってしまうのではないか（でもこれは変だ）ということになりました。

Comment: 「共有ロックの所持者が自分しかいない場合は、それを　exclusive lock に書き換えることができる」というような動作を　mysql はしてると思ってます。

Comment: なるほど。書き換えることできるのであれば、可能そうですね（厳密には本当にそうしているのか調べる必要があるかもしれませんが）。